# Dropzonejs resort appended images

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have dropzone box and I've implemented sortable into it. As my form submits with html and not ajax I had to add hidden inputs where I push my selected images with dropzonejs therefore I could get them in back-end.

**So far everything I explained above is working**

#### Issue

As I mentioned I've implemented sortable functionality into dropzonejs and **it does sort images** in dropzone box, **but not in my appended hidden input**

In order to get sorted images in back-end I need to apply that sortable into my appended input as well.

#### Code

`HTML`

```
//Drop zone box
<div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="#">
  <div class="fallback">
     <input name="cimages[]" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
// append hidden input include selected images for back-end use
<div id="botofform"></div>
```

`Script`

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
  },
  autoProcessQueue : false,
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one",
  maxFiles: 15, // Maximum Number of Files
  maxFilesize: 8, // MB
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
  dictFileTooBig: 'Image is bigger than 8MB',

  // append hidden input and add selected images
  accept: function(file) {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      fileReader.onloadend = function() {
          let content = fileReader.result;
          $('#botofform').append('<input type="hidden" class="cimages" name="cimages[]" value="'+ content +'">');
          file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
      }
      file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-complete");
  }
});
// reorder images in dropzone box (need to get this results into "$('#botofform').append" above)
$(function(){
  $(".dropzone").sortable({
    items:'.dz-preview',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.5,
    containment: '.dropzone',
    distance: 20,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
  });
});
```

#### Question

1. How can I apply sortable results into my appended input?
2. How do I reduce `$('#botofform')` items (inputs) when an image gets removed by dropzonejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **data-attribute** for both your `div` where image is added and `input` field .So, whenever new file is uploaded you can use `setAttribute("data-id", count)` here *count* can be any random number only make sure this value should be same for both `input` and `div` because this will help us to remove and sort inputs .

Now , for sorting inputs you can use [**stop event**](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop) this will get called when sorting is stop .Inside this you can loop through `dropzone` div and then get attribute which we have added earlier using this attribute we can find the input and append same to `botofform` div.

Finally , for deleting files you can use [**remove files**](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-removedfile) event this will get called whenever `remove` link is clicked so here you simply need to get that `data-id` which is added to div then use this attribute to remove input as well.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var count;
var random;
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
  },
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one",
  maxFiles: 15, // Maximum Number of Files
  maxFilesize: 8, // MB
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
  dictFileTooBig: 'Image is bigger than 8MB',

  // append hidden input and add selected images
  accept: function(file) {

    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    fileReader.onloadend = function() {
      random = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      count = $(".dz-complete").length + "_" + random;
      let content = fileReader.result;
      console.log(count)
      //add dataid
      $('#botofform').append('<input type="text" class="cimages" name="cimages[]" data-id = "' + count + '" value="' + content + '">');

      file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
      file.previewElement.setAttribute("data-id", count);

    }

    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-complete");

  },
  removedfile: function(file) {
    console.log("inside remove --" + file.previewElement.getAttribute("data-id"))
    var ids = file.previewElement.getAttribute("data-id") // get attr where file is been removed 
    $("#botofform input[data-id=" + ids + "]").remove() //remove input field as well
    file.previewElement.remove(); //remove file


  }
});

$(function() {
  $(".dropzone").sortable({
    items: '.dz-preview',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.5,
    containment: '.dropzone',
    distance: 20,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      //cloned div
      var cloned = $('div#botofform').clone()
      $('#botofform').html("") //empty it
      //loop through dropzone..
      $('.dropzone .dz-complete').each(function() {
        var data_id = $(this).data('id') //get data-id
        $(cloned).find("input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").clone().appendTo($('#botofform')) //find input which has that data-id and append same to bottmform
      });


    }

  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
//Drop zone box
<div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="#">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="cimages[]" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="botofform"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, here is screenshot of my results  https://ibb.co/kmhMJc4

Comment: another one i found is this:  in div `botofform` all inputs have the same id.  https://ibb.co/LJbskxb

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle for your current code ?  Also , expand div `dropzone` there will be different divs for each file see if there `data-id` is different and this `data-id` should match inputs and did you run above demo code ? It's working fine or not?

Comment: Ok I am making jsfiddle (however basically is your code). `about the ids` in dropzone div all are correct, but in `botofform` div all inputs ids are the same and they won't get updated on remove nor on sort.

Comment: even here in your code you can see part of problem https://ibb.co/XXbN43T

Comment: I've played around with this code and tried to change appended input ids and match them with dropzone ids. It was working just fine, so the problem with your code is that this line only gets id of latest image `$('#botofform').append('<input type="text" class="cimages" name="cimages[]" data-id = "' + count + '" value="' + content + '">');` it does not get correct ids as dropzone previews.

Comment: Hi i tested this many times on my end ..not sure why i am not getting that behaviour :( . Still if you are saying input box doesn't match with data-id of dropzone .. can you put `file.previewElement.setAttribute("data-id", count);` line after `$('#botofform').append..` . and test again ?

Comment: Also , increase random range i.e : put `1000` there instead of `100`

Comment: Hi, That would mess up even dropzone inputs now all of them have same id. `PS` how you checked excatly and didn't get same id for all inputs in `botofform` ? just open your console and you see all ids in `botofform` are the same\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226185/discussion-between-swati-and-mafortis).